# Wordpress Child Pages in Alphabetical Order

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm using a specific piece of code to display the child pages names, featured images and excerpt on the parent page. This code works fine, but I've been trying to modify it to display the child posts alphabeticaly without success.

I've tried changing the ORDER BY menu_order to ORDER BY title or ORDER BY name but it breaks the page.

If anybody has some hints or tips, your advice would be greatly appreciated!

```
<?php

    $pageChildren = $wpdb->get_results("
        SELECT *
        FROM $wpdb->posts
        WHERE post_parent = ".$post->ID."
        AND post_type = 'page'
        ORDER BY menu_order
    ", 'OBJECT');

    if ( $pageChildren ) :
        foreach ( $pageChildren as $pageChild ) :
            setup_postdata( $pageChild );
            ?>
            <?php $imagethumb = get_post_meta($pageChild->ID, 'image-thumb', $single = true); ?>

<div id="solutionbutton">
<div id="centerbutton">
        <img src="<?php echo $imagethumb; ?>" />
        <h4><?php print '<a href="' . get_permalink( $pageChild->ID ) . '">' . get_the_title( $pageChild->ID ) . '</a>'; ?></h4>
        </div>
        <div id="entry">
            <?php echo excerpt(13); ?>
</br></br>
            <a href="<?php echo get_permalink($pageChild->ID); ?>">Read More...</a>
        </div>
</div>
        <?php
        endforeach;
    endif;
    ?>

            </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
$pageChildren = $wpdb->get_results("
    SELECT *
    FROM $wpdb->posts
    WHERE post_parent = ".$post->ID."
    AND post_type = 'page'
    ORDER BY post_title
", 'OBJECT');
```

It is for pages. But is there a feature to specify **post** parent? If so, change `post_type = 'page'` to `post_type = 'post'`. 
Btw, your code can be refactored using WordPress built-in function like this:

```
$pageChildren = get_posts(array(
    'post_type'=>'page', 
    'nopaging'=>true, 
    'orderby'=>'menu_order'
));
```

Comment: I used your first solution and it worked like a charm!

Answer (score 0):

```
**Try the code.....**

$args = array(
    'orderby' => 'title',
    'order'=> 'DESC',
    'post_parent' => $post->ID,
    'post_type' => 'page'
    );

$get_childrens = get_children($args);
print_r($get_childrens);
```